# String split into dictionary containing lists in python

Tags: python, split

I have to split a string that looks like;

```
'{ a:[(b,c), (d,e)] , b: [(a,c), (c,d)]}'
```

and convert it to a dict whose values are a list containing tuples like;

```
{'a':[('b','c'), ('d','e')] , 'b': [('a','c'), ('c','d')]}
```

In my case;
The above string was just an example. So what I am trying to do actually is that I'm getting a response from server. At server side, the response is proper dictionary with lists and stuff. But it sends to my client in a string format somehow. for example

```
u"{'write_times': [ (1.658935546875, 1474049078179.095), (1.998779296875, 1474049078181.098)],  'read_times': [(0.825927734375, 1474049447696.7249), (1.4638671875, 1474049447696.7249)]}"
```

I want it to be just like it was at the server side.

```
{'write_times': [ ('1.65893554687', '1474049078179.095'), ('1.998779296875', '1474049078181.098')],  'read_times': [('0.825927734375', '1474049447696.7249'), ('1.4638671875', '1474049447696.7249')]}
```

The solution you proposed may not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you "Trust" the string? If it is generated from user input, then it is not trusted. It matters since it may be possible to use `eval` if the string is trusted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @James K I have edited my question a bit.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to know where this string is coming from, but, assuming this is what you have and you cannot change that, you can pre-process the string putting alphanumerics into quotes and using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to *safely* eval it:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s = '{ a:[(b,c), (d,e)] , b: [(a,c), (c,d)]}'
>>> literal_eval(re.sub(r"(\w+)", r"'\1'", s))
{'a': [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e')], 'b': [('a', 'c'), ('c', 'd')]}
```

Comment: Was going to post the identical solution but realized that it would break for `{ a: [(b, c, something else)] }`. Not sure if that's an issue or not.

Comment: @JustinNiessner good point, the solution is not that reliable at this point and can break in many different ways, but I hope this is something the OP can start with (or stop, if realized the complexity of the problem :))..interesting to know where is this coming from..thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, guys!

Comment: @alecxe . I have edited my question a bit. Added my real scenario. Thanks for the help, guys!